# How do I hook up ParseHub API to Parse

Tags: json, api, parse-platform, hook, webhooks

How to connect ParseHub API to Parse.com.

I've a website that I want to get the data from and I did it with parsehub.com,and now after I've build the app with swift and parse backend and I want to get the content from the website by ParseHub.

**My Question is how to hook both projects form ParseHub API to Parse API "API console" or webhooks?**

I did read about POST GET DELETE PUT request's but 
One Way I did which is export ParseHub to CSV/JSON then upload it manually to Parse.com but I want to make Automatic with an API

Parsehub API
https://www.parsehub.com/docs/guides/api_tutorial